# How to access superclass method from the client?

Tags: python, oop

I'm new to Python and I have the following simple hierarchy under package "dao":

```
class BaseDao:
    def __init__(self):
        self.connection = ... # initialize the connection
        self.connection.autocommit = False

    def get_connection(self):
        return self.connection

    def close(self):
        self.connection.close()

class PriceMomentumDao(BaseDao):
    def __init__(self):
        super(PriceMomentumDao, self).__init__()
```

and now my client code:

```
import from dao PriceMomentumDao

myDao = PriceMomentumDao
myDao.get_connection()
```

but then I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'get_connection'
```

Comment: You're missing the parenthesis on the creation of the object, it should go like this; `myDao = PriceMomentumDao()`. In addition to that, the import syntax is not correct. Use this instead: `from dao import PriceMomentumDao`

Comment: that leads to the error `myDao = PriceMomentumDao()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`

Comment: You aren't instantiating a PriceMomentumDao in the above code. The syntax for class instantiation is instance = classname()

Comment: Your `import` statement in the question is also invalid syntax.

Comment: If someone could post an answer that illustrates the correct way to do what's intended as the OP would be more useful rather than writing a million comments ... or?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things are wrong here:

- you gave your module and contained class the same, increasing your confusion (Python doesn't require you to do this, that's a Java thing)
- you didn't create an instance of the class.

Use

```
myDao = PriceMomentumDao.PriceMomentumDao()
```

or adjust your import:

```
from dao.PriceMomentumDao import PriceMomentumDao

# ...

myDao = PriceMomentumDao()
```

You may want to heed the advice given in the [Python styleguide, PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions), and use `price_momentum_dao` as the module name instead.

If this is Python 2, make sure you also inherit from `object`, or you won't be able to use new-style class features such as `super()`:

```
class BaseDao(object):
```

Comment: Thanks but now I get the error `super(PriceMomentumDao, self).__init__() TypeError: must be type, not classobj`

Comment: @GiovanniAzua: you must inherit from `object` for new-style class features such as `super()` to work.